# Visual Studio C# unable to get System.Windows.Forms working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, forms, visual-studio-2022

I created a project in visual studio using the C# WPF Application (this is what was recommended to me by esri for cartography purposes).

I started to create the log inform everything went well using the [PAGE].xaml resource. Once I was happy with the page I created a new one which will be loaded when the log-in page is successful.

I have the code

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

Application_Main_MainPage form1 = new Application_Main_MainPage();
form1.Show();
this.Hide();
```

But I keep getting an error that the type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The biggest tutorial was to go into the project and add the reference which I did but it did not work.

[image: My Project]

[image: Going to the Reference]

[image: Adding the forms reference]

Has not worked.

Would someone be able to give a resolution

Comment: What is the reason for you to create WPF application while adding a COM reference to Windows.Forms?

Comment: I was following the tutorials online and this was the closest that I could find that matched the tutorial. If you know of a different way I would be happy to try it out.

I am unsure what is causing the issue

Comment: I think you could be conflating examples for wpf with one for win forms?

Comment: I understand that that maybe happening though how do I get the System.Windows.Forms to with with an .xaml Window

Or if not what is the correct way to go to a new .xaml Window. My apologies I am using .xaml Windows

Comment: I've found these tutorials simple to follow: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLI-F7ydFjNpC2lJ6UI-ZA2FnwR3fiP1IZ (Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with the creator of these videos).

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid Thank you for these tutorials I will look into them. Yeah esri kind of threw my for a loop with this change over

Comment: You can open your csproj file with Notepad to see if the System.Windows version referenced in it is consistent with the System.Windows version referenced in the Solution Explorer